# What would be the recommended solution for this services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

In this Microsoft article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0 says it is **not recommended** to use in the **ConfigureServices method**, in the **Startup.cs class** of a **.NET Core 2.2 project**.

```
services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService()
```

Complete C# code below:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>();

    var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddProfile(new MappingProfileConfig(services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IMyService>()));
    });

    var mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();

    services.AddSingleton(mapper);

}
```

Has anyone got any best practice suggestion for this please?

Thank you

Comment: automapper has [built in](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core) dependency injection routines. You can [search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=automapper+dependency+injection) to find more examples.

Comment: that is because in the ConfigureServices you should have access to instances and/or types.  So calling BuildServiceProvider creates a second dependency container.  Instead your should use the AddOptions and options pattern